# How to get the width of a polymer element inside the JS of the polymer element

Tags: polymer, web-component

I have a polymer element and inside its Javascript I am trying to find its width and height as it is inside the DOM. I tried many ways but I always get 0 back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

...and here's the one which works for me:

Add the `Polymer.IronResizableBehavior` behaviour to your element (see https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-resizable-behavior). Then your element will be sent a `iron-resize` event when it gets sized. In the handler, check to see whether it's not 0; if not, you're golden.

Untested code follows:

```
<dom-module id="hard-chicken">
  <template>
    Hello <span>{{name}}</span>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'hard-chicken',
    behaviors: [ Polymer.IronResizableBehavior ],
    listeners: { "iron-resize": "onWidthChange" },
    onWidthChange: function() {
      var w = this.offsetWidth;
      if (w > 0)
        console.log("width is now ", w);
    }
  });
</script>
```

This took way, *way* too long to figure out...

Comment: I will add a gotcha which I discovered the other day. The event doesn't *always* fire. My app was loading a `.woff` font; the font would take a while to load, and after it finished loading, everything would relayout --- but the event wouldn't fire. YMMV.

Comment: This isn't working for me. The function that is called when the resize event happens still returns 0 as the width :(

Answer (score 3):

polymer 1.0

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- 
Here's where you'll define your element. You can define multiple elements
if you want, but the package name will be taken from the first custom
element you define in the file. You can also document your element! For
more info, see [the docs](https://ele.io/docs).

@element hard-chicken
-->
<dom-module id="hard-chicken" attributes="name">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
    Hello {{name}}
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({is:'hard-chicken', 
      /**
       * The name of the person you want to say hello to.
       * @attribute name
       * @type string
       * @default "Polymer Dev"
       */
      name: 'Polymer Dev',
      ready: function() {
        console.log(this.offsetWidth);
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Sorry but, this can't work at all. In Polymer 1 you can't use inline attributes on dom-module. The style tag should be outside the template tag, the script tag outside the dom-module tag. If you want to expose the name property, you should use the properties property on the Polymer object.

Comment: I forgot to mention that also the {{name}} variable should be wrapped between a tag because Polymer v1 doesn't support string concatenation.

Comment: re: string concatenation - as of v1.2.0, Polymer does now [support](https://blog.polymer-project.org/releases/2015/11/02/release-1.2.0/) it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to calculate the width in the `attached` handler of the element, as that comes last when the unit is actually attached to the DOM.

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order

```
attached: function() {
  console.log(this.offsetWidth);
}
```

Comment: Did this solution actually work for someone? I've tried all the callbacks (attached as well), even getting the width of child / shadow elements, this.getBoundingClientRect().width and in all the cases it keeps returning 0. It would be nice if there wasn't need to use any timeouts.

Comment: Nope, this returns 0 until the element gets sized.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
attached: function() {
  this.async(function() {
    console.log(this.offsetWidth);
  });
}
```

Read the documentation at:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#initialization-order

Answer (score 1):

```
<dom-module id="hard-chicken">
  <style>
      :host {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  <template>
    Hello <span>{{name}}</span>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'hard-chicken',
    /**
     * The name of the person you want to say hello to.
     * @attribute name
     * @type string
     * @default "Polymer Dev"
     */
    properties: {
      name: {
        value : 'Polymer Dev',
        type: String
      }
    },
    _getWidth: function () {
      console.log(this.offsetWidth);
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.async(this._getWidth, 500);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work --- `async()` runs its callback after the current method has finished executing, but before the next event is processed. Which means that you element hasn't been sized and `offsetWidth` will still be 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- You can import core and paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<!-- 
Here's where you'll define your element. You can define multiple elements
if you want, but the package name will be taken from the first custom
element you define in the file. You can also document your element! For
more info, see [the docs](https://ele.io/docs).

@element hard-chicken
-->
<polymer-element name="hard-chicken" attributes="name">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
    Hello {{name}}
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('hard-chicken', {
      /**
       * The name of the person you want to say hello to.
       * @attribute name
       * @type string
       * @default "Polymer Dev"
       */
      name: 'Polymer Dev',
      ready: function() {
        console.log(this.offsetWidth);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```